# C++ class size template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have the following function:

```
template <uint8_t N1, uint8_t N2, uint8_t N3>
Shape<N3> func(const Shape<N1> &shape1, const Shape<N2> &shape2)
{
    return Shape<N3>();
}
```

Definition of Shape:

```
template <uint8_t N> class Shape;
```

Is there a way to deduce N1 and N2 by the Shapes passed to the function?

```
Shape<3> shape1 = {1, 2, 3};
Shape<2> shape2 = {4, 5};
Shape<4> shape3 = func<4>(shape1, shape2);
```

Instead of:

```
Shape<4> shape3 = func<3, 2, 4>(shape1, shape2);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should arrange your template parameters so that the ones that need to be explicitly specified are at the beginning, and the ones that can be deduced from the arguments are at the end:

```
template <uint8_t N3, uint8_t N1, uint8_t N2>
Shape<N3> func(const Shape<N1> &shape1, const Shape<N2> &shape2)
{
    return ...;
}

Shape<3> shape1 = {1, 2, 3};
Shape<2> shape2 = {4, 5};
Shape<4> shape3 = func<4>(shape1, shape2);
```

Here, `N3` is explicitly specified as 4 while `N1` and `N2` are deduced from the argument types, so all template parameters have values and the code compiles. If you leave `N3` at the end, then you will be forced to explicitly specify `N1` and `N2` in order to explicitly specify `N3`.

Comment: Seems very intuitive. Unfortunately, the solution still produces an error: no matching function for call to ‘func<4>(Shape<3>&, Shape<2>&)’.
explicitly writing the template arguments still works.

Comment: @TheTompiler It works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/xe1qT6Wor . If you're having compilation errors, you need to show the actual code that doesn't compile (reduced to a minimal reproducible example).

Comment: I had some other issue that I have now solved. Your solution works! thank you very much!